# Can we get geodesic equation from map projections of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it possible to derive geodesic equation on an n-manifold given its (n-1) projection, e.g., given a sinusoidal projection equations y=a & x=b*cos(a) of a sphere on a flat plain, where a is latitude & b is longitude, can we deduce the equation for geodesic curves on this projection/plain/map, if yes how? Alternatively, how can we derive required metric for the manifold, sphere in this example from its given projection equations?

Comment: What do you mean by "its projection equations"? What do you project and on what?

Comment: It would help to add to the question exactly how you're thinking of an $n$-manifold. Are you thinking of something like a sphere in Euclidean three-space, and by _projections_ do you mean "orthogonal projections to a hyperplane"? Or are you using "projection" in the sense of cartography, a general transformation from a sphere to a plane region? (Separately, the _projective geometry_ tag has a different, technical meaning than orthogonal projections; if you edit the question, it might be good to remove the tag as well.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have modified the question, hope this will explain the query better!

Comment: @rim It seems you think of manifolds as embedded hypersurfaces of the euclidean space: only a few Riemannian manifolds realize as hypersurfaces!

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense to me. Can you focus, carefully and with details, on the case of the sphere. We know what the geodesics on a sphere are. Are you projecting to a plane? What are sinusoidal projections? And then you seem to be trying to go backwards. Just rewrite and be detailed and explicit.